# DRF field validation on subset of Model's field

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

Allow me to first sketch the relevant parts of my Django/DRF project using some relevant snippets (Note that the following code snippets do not result in working code, but are there to show the overall structure of my problem):

`models.py`

```
class Sample(models.model):
    property_one = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=property_one_validators)
    property_two = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=property_two_validators)
    property_three = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=property_three_validators)
    property_four = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=property_four_validators)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer = SampleSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def method_one(self, request, pk):
        # Require property_one and property_three in request.data

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def method_two(self, request, pk):
        # Require property_one and property_two in request.data

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def method_three(self, request, pk):
        # Require property_two and property_four in request.data
```

As you can see various subsets of the `Sample` model's parameters are used within the available API requests. What I would like to do is validate the required parameters within each API request using their respective validators (e.g. validate `property_one` with `property_one_validators` defined in `models.py`).

From what I understand from the `Serializer` documentation, you are able to use `validate` to validate a complete filled in Model class (e.g. with `property_one` to `property_four`), but I would want use the same Serializer or at least its functionality to validate the fields separately (e.g. use the `SampleSerializer` in some way to validate `property_one` separately).

My question is ultimately whether this functionality is present and if this is possible. If this is not the case, I would love to hear your take on what the most generic way of doing this validation is, rather than creating a Serializer class for each subset of properties.

Comment: you can make a base  serializer class with custom validate function.

Comment: Are you looking for [DRF field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#field-level-validation) ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I assume that the `validate` method of the `SampleSerializer` currently makes use of the defined validators within the fields of the `Sample`. If I were to add these field-specific functions, I would think that I am repeating myself unnecessarily. However, if there is no alternative, I can indeed still consider this approach to accomplish my goal though. What is your take on this? 

Moreover, this documentation mentions that this is for specifying **custom** field-level validation. Does this mean that there is already standard field-level validation present in the Serializers?

Comment: *"...I am repeating myself unnecessarily..."* I don't understand what you have done already to repeat yourself.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Well, I agree it is not s much repeating as writing code which I think might already be present in the default behavior of the `Serializer`. Please also look at the edit of my previous comment; do you know whether the `Serializer` defines "default" or "standard" field-level validation?